# Google add-on : restrict the google picker API

Tags: security, google-apps-script, api-key, add-on, restriction

I have made a google add on and web app that uses the Google Picker API, by opening a pop-up to allow the user to select a folder on Drive and use it on the add on.

I now want to restrict my API key so that only my add on can use it, so I am restricting the key to a website, and I am adding the URL I want it to be restricted to, but I cannot find the URL that I need to input here.

I thaught it would be the URL of my web-app : https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXXXX/exec
However, it seems that the right url is of the form : https://XXXXX-script.googleusercontent.com/YYY

I can find in the console of my web-app what looks like the XXX part, but I'm not sure about two things :

- Is the XXX ficed or can it change depending on the user ?
- What should the YYY be ?

Right now I am authorizing *script.googleusercontent.com/* but i am not sure it is well secured.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: What tests have you done so far to reach this conclusion? I tested with devtools and the content seems to be generated from `https://XXXXX-script.googleusercontent.com/blank`, where the `XXXX-` is unique to each script, but it's the same for different deployments of the Web App. The `blank` part is always the same, have you seen something different? I think you could try the full `https://XXXXX-script.googleusercontent.com/` and it should remain consistent for the same script project but I couldn't find any supporting documentation.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Actually, I saw that there were three calls in the console : https://XXXXX-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel, https://XXXXX-script.googleusercontent.com/static/macros/client/js/ZZZZ-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__fr.js and https://XXXXX-script.googleusercontent.com/blank. I have tried to autorize all three from my API Key restriction page on GCC, hower it always gets me a wrong API error when opening the google picker. If I authorize https://XXXXX-script.googleusercontent.com/* then it works.

Comment: If you're including the `XXXX-` string then it's unique to your script so in theory it should be safe. The strange part is that according to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#redirects), this URL should be "one-time", so I would expect this ID to change. However, In my tests it was unique to each project but it persisted, which doesn't seem one-time. It could be that it changes after some time but I have not tested long enough to know for sure.

Comment: Yes, this is also the conclusion I came to on my side. I will test in time to see if it persists. In the meantime, if anyone has more information about this I will be glad to have it !